# Maven Site deploy fails with SCP Connection Refused - Windows

Tags: java, maven-2, release, release-management

I'm using the maven release plugin on hudson. I'm trying to release the project. Everything works till a point where release process tries to do the site deploy. When it tries to do that, maven fails with scp connection refused error.

Here is the log:

```
        Using private key: C:\hudson\.ssh\id_rsa
        scp://somehost.somecompany.com/c:/hudson/userContent/some_javadoc/1.9.16/ - Session: Connection refused 
    scp://somehost.somecompany.com/c:/hudson/userContent/some_javadoc/1.9.16/ - Session: Disconnecting 
    scp://somehost.somecompany.com/c:/hudson/userContent/some_javadoc/1.9.16/ - Session: Disconnected 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    [ERROR] BUILD ERROR 
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
        [INFO] Error uploading site Embedded error: 
    The host was not known and was not accepted by the configuration: somehost.somecompany.com reject HostKey: somehost.somecompany.com 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 31 seconds [INFO] Finished at: Fri Nov 19 10:19:36 CST 2010 
[INFO] Final Memory: 83M/199M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have the server and the credentials in the settings.xml. I have also specified the site in the distribution management section of the pom.xml.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with Maven or the release plugin per se - `somehost.somecompany.com` is refusing your connection. Are you positive that these credentials work on their own?

You can try launching Maven with the `-X` flag to have it spit out all of it's debugging information, hopefully this plugin will be logging more helpful information about what it is doing as a part of attempting to make this connection.

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'                                    Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'                                       These are the exceptions thrown

Comment: Is there a way to skip site:delpoy from the release process?

Comment: What is the full `mvn` command you are invoking? I don't think `site:deploy` happens by default, you might be either explicitly creating the `site` or your pom.xml is configured to generate it.

Comment: Hi I resolved the problem by using file protocol rather than SCP. I used file protocol , because I was deploying the site to my local hudson box. Thanks for helping out. I have another issue now. One of the sources jar is getting deployed twice and because of which the release is failing.

Comment: @ Vanchinathan Chandrasekaran: "I have another issue now. One of the sources jar is getting deployed twice and because of which the release is failing."  ==> Ask this as a NEW question and you'll get more help with it.